# How do I Wrap Functions Presented by plumber for Work in Promises

Tags: r, parallel-processing, future, plumber, r-promises

I have about 20 typical functions like:

```
echo_delayed <- function(j){
  jj <<- j # for debugging purpose
  Sys.sleep(1.5)
  print(paste0('echo_delayed - ', now() %>% toString(), " ", j))
}
```

All of them have `j` parameter that is an embraced JSON string parsed in these functions. The functions produce different kinds of outputs. Typically `ggplot()... %>% print()`, string or byte stream. These functions are presented by `plumber`. For instance:

```
#* @post /echo_delayed
#* @serializer contentType list(type="text/html; charset=UTF-8")
echo_delayed
```

Using [this](https://rdrr.io/github/rstudio/plumber/src/inst/plumber/13-promises/plumber.R) sample I am trying to wrap some of them to work in a non-blocking mode:

```
time <- function(name_, name = name_) {
  paste0(name, ": ", Sys.time())
}

new_promise <- function() {
  promise(function(resolve, reject){ resolve(NULL) })
}

add_echo_delayed <- function(p) {
    p <- then(p, function(value) {
      echo_delayed(value) 
      "" # return value
    })
  p
}

#' @post /echo_delayed
#' @serializer contentType list(type="text/html; charset=UTF-8")
function() {
  new_promise() %>%
    add_echo_delayed() %...>%
    time("echo_delayed")
}
```

However it is not running in a separate thread and other queries are waiting until `echo_delayed()` is done with calculation.

The functions from above mentioned sample (with minimal edits) are working fine:

```
sleep_count <- 5
add_async_sleep <- function(p) {
  n <- 20
  for (i in 1:(sleep_count * n)) {
    p <- then(p, function(value) {
      Sys.sleep(1/n)
      "" # return value
    })
  }
  p
}

#' @post /async_post
#' @serializer contentType list(type="text/html; charset=UTF-8")
function() {
  new_promise() %>%
    add_async_sleep() %...>%
    time("async_post")
}
```

It stops working if I break splitting the sample function into pieces:

```
add_async_sleep2 <- function(p) {
    p <- then(p, function(value) {
      Sys.sleep(sleep_count)
      "" # return value
    })
  p
}
```

I am stuck. Could anyone please help me to properly wrap the function `echo_delayed()` so that it starts running in a separate thread and the parameter `j` is passed into it?

Comment: I don't have the answer, but I should say these are the kind of Q&As that need to be widely available and addressed if plumber and r promises are to become mainstream. If you want to people to innovate using this software, they need to be equipped to do so. Great Q @asd-tm

Comment: Thank you @J.Doe. very kind of you. I hope finally I get a function like `function(FUN, ...)` or even `function(FUN)()`